# Change data in table and copying to new table

Tags: list, excel, count, vba

I would like to make a macro in Excel, but I think it's too complicated to do it with recording... That's why I'm coming here for assistance.

**The file:**
I have a list of warehouse boxes all containing a specific ID, location (town), location (in or out) and a date.
Whenever boxes change location, this needs to be changed in this list and the date should be adjusted accordingly (this should be a manual input, since the changing of the list might not happen on the same day as the movement of the box).

On top of that, I need to count the number of times the location changes from in to out (so that I know how many times the box has been used).

**The way of inputting:**

A good way of inputting would be that you can make a list of the boxes where you want to change the information from, f.e.:

```
ID    | Location (town) | Location (in/out) | Date
------------------------------------------------
123-4 | Paris           | OUT               | 9-1-14

124-8 | London          | IN                | 9-1-14

999-84| London          | IN                | 10-1-14

124-8 | New York        | OUT               | 9-1-14
```

Then I'd make a button that uses the macro to change the data mentioned above in the master list (where all the boxes are listed) and on some way count the number of times OUT changes to IN etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately we are not a code-writing service, you want a freelance developer for that. If you make an attempt at this yourself and come across some problems feel free to ask about those here, it's probably worth checking the [Help Center](http://Stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: I would suggest a "work" sheet where you enter the data sequentially as it occurs, possibly in a Table, possibly with data validation lists for the cell entries; and then a Summary sheet where you display the last entry for each ID on the worksheet.  That way you have both an audit trail, and the current location report you want.  You can get the number of movements on the summary sheet by using a COUNTIF function.  I think that is what db579 is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want updated in your Main List but I don't think you need Macros at all to achieve this. You can count the number of times and box location has changed by simply making a list of all your boxes in one column and the count in the next column. For the count use the formula COUNTIFS to count all the rows where the box id is the same and the location is in/out. Check VLOOKUP for updating your main list values.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answering! Could you explain a little more into detail? My masterlist looks the same way as the small table I'd use for inputting the data (like I mentioned in the first post), but with an extra column that counts the number of times out changes to in.